# How do I pass a parameter to the constructor of a gwtp view?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I have a gui control I wish to use ([GWTCropper](http://gwt-cropper.co.uk/)).

It's main control GWTCropper allows me to "crop" an image (I can capture the coordinates of the moveable square on my image).

Only problem is it takes the URL of the image to crop as a constructor parameter (and no other way).

I thus preferably need to  either

1. Pass the image url in as a constructor parameter (this would be preferable I think)
2. Defer the call to later (not sure exactly when or how it will be called if I remove it from the constructor though).

I've looked at factories and assisted inject but no traction on how to customise the creation of the view. I know I can send the parameter to the presenter but not sure how I can gain control of the view and its lifecyle.

I've noticed there is a method on AbstractPresenterModule: bindPresenterWidgetFactory but I can't see how this helps me *parameterise* each view...

Comment: I think you will have to defer the creation of the `GWTCropper` to a later point. 
How do you construct the image URL ? Does the `Presenter` pass it to your `View` ?

Comment: hmmm... yes, that is what I ended up doing. I created a simple panel as a place holder for the gwt cropper and then created and added the gwt cropper via a method call from presenter to view. Does mean as always, that I "burn" a div